# Download from REST API with authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, rest, download, restsharp

I have REST Api which is my data repository for ASP MVC application (instead of database). I am using RestSharp + access token to communicate with RestAPI. 
What is the best approach to let users download files (served by rest api). The requirement is that only authorized users can download files.

I could generate links directly to API but I need authorization.

I could create method in ASP MVC which downloads file from API and then serve it to end user, but then I would had to download it into server memory first.

Is there a way to "stream" such file from REST API through ASP MVC to end user without server high performance consumption?
I develop both - web application and rest api, so I have control over both sides.